# Have not received expected automatic support email -- did my query reach support?

Tags: support, email, contact

I submitted a support query using [this form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) about 50-60 minutes ago and it said I should receive an email "shortly"... There is no email in my inbox or spam folders. Does that mean support didn't receive my query?

Comment: You expect free support on a free website to have an average turnaround time of *one hour*? Wow.

Comment: I only expected what the form's reply suggested by my definition of shortly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sorry, by "shortly" we mean "we will reply to you soon". There is no automatic responder. A real human<sup>1</sup> will respond as soon as possible.

(In your specific case, you should receive a response on Monday if not before, although I make no promises that someone will be working on the weekend. I can confirm, though, that we received your message.)

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>(or a cat)</sub>

Comment: Watch out, someone will sue you for not actually having a cat respond to their emails!

Comment: cat or unicorn?

Comment: Just in case you want your cat to start programming: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921455/how-do-i-program-using-cat :D